How to export (or view) test results for all test cases in ADO test plans?
IN ADO we can manually open a test case (in our case grouped by Sprint).
Then double click on the test case to see the history of the test's results:
View of test case:
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/lGVTKSF9.png)
View of double click on test case to see history of test results (per test event):
enter image description here
Without having to manually open each and every test, within each and every test plan to see the history of results is there a quicker way to get this data?
Purpose: Determine the % DEFECTS / FAILS per test plan and in total to date.
Struggling to find a short-cut way to view all results for all test cases in one view.

Currently we cannot check all histories for all test cases in a view, but for daily outcome, we can check in the progress report. Please check the details below, let me know if you have any quires, thanks.

The test case could be executed multi times in one day, the history records all execution outcome.
It's not supported to check all histories for all test cases in test plan within a view currently.
But for daily outcome, you can check the testplan Progress report outcome trend for each day to find the test case outcome(passed,failed,notrun).

Please note Report data is updated approximately every 15 minutes. Do not use this report for real-time analysis or reporting.
I can fully understand your concern, if the report doesn't meet your requirement, it's recommended to raise a feature request in community link, thanks.
